Custom QML Module not found on import
I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and can't seem to find the solution.
I'm trying to setup an application that is split up into several QML modules. I wanted to have every bit of code in a logical place to make it more maintainable when the project grows.
A part of the folder structure I have is as follows:
D:MyProject/
│   CMakeLists.txt
│
└───Controller
    │   .qmlls.ini
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    │   Main.qml
    ├───src
    │       main.cpp
    │
    └───modules
        │
        └───CustomViews
            │   .qmlls.ini
            │   CMakeLists.txt
            │   MenuToolBar.qml
            │   ViewServers.qml
            │
            └───src
                   Backend.cpp
                   Backend.h  

I have a main program and several modules, the goal is to import these modules into the main file to be able to call on them.
Let me show you the CMakeLists files:
CustomViews/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# Set the module name
set(MODULE_NAME "CustomViews")

qt_add_library(${MODULE_NAME} STATIC)

set_target_properties(${MODULE_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC ON)
target_link_libraries(${MODULE_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)

qt_add_qml_module(${MODULE_NAME}
    URI ${MODULE_NAME}
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        ViewServers.qml
        MenuToolBar.qml

    # SOURCES

    # RESOURCES
)

Project/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(MyProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

set(QT_QML_GENERATE_QMLLS_INI ON)

add_subdirectory(Controller)

Controller/CMakeLists.txt
project(Controller VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(${PROJECT_NAME}
    URI Controller
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        Main.qml
)

# Add module subdirectories
add_subdirectory(modules/CustomViews)

# Register local modules. "${ModuleName}plugin"
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE CustomViewsplugin
)


# Add the resources.qrc file to the project to include all images in the shared "images" folder and link the resources to the executable
qt_add_resources(RESOURCES ../Shared/resources/resources.qrc)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${RESOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS QuickControls2)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::QuickControls2)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
#    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.xLiveController
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)


I've already tried adding the path to CustomViews to the QML_IMPORT_PATH but that didn't do the trick.
list(APPEND QML_IMPORT_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Controller/modules/CustomViews")

set(QML_IMPORT_PATH ${QML_IMPORT_PATH}
    CACHE STRING "Qt Creator extra qml import paths"
    FORCE
)

I also tried playing with the URI and Target of the qt_add_qml_module() function to see if this does something but that didn't fix the warning

The error you're showing appears to be coming from Qt Creator. In my experience, often the compilation succeeds even though the IDE thinks there are errors. Have you tried actually building/running it?

Yeah the application builds and runs just fine. it's just annoying that the IDE keeps giving errors even if it runs just fine.
